# Could ios 4.3.3 support he-aac software decoding?

Tags: ipad, audio, decode, aac

i have two ipads with two version. one is ios 4.2.1, another is 4.3.3.
i write an app which plays he-aac format audio and it should have playback mixing behavior .So i init the audio session, set the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback category(i playback the audio while the screen locked) and set kaudiosessionproperty_overridecategorymixwithothers. i use audio queue to play it (system can decode and playback )
The result is the app in ios 4.2.1 can't play while that in ios 4.3.3 play normally.ios developer library document tells me that app with playback mixing behavior and decode aac can not access hardware decode.
so i think ios 4.3.3 support he-aac software decoding but 4.2.1 can't!

but ios developer library document also says that it don't support he-aac software decode...
i confused...

thank you very much for answer!

there is reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html